# AngularJS SEO - Once and for all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, seo

I'm in a big project with 15 sub sites and 13 different schema pages.
Currently, the site is based on `ui.route` for all pages and my data set by `$http` angular request.
After tests and trials on search console its looks like google don't see all my pages except the home page and data from `$http` request don't showing up.
What I'm doing wrong?

### What I'm doing so far is:

**Set base tag in the `<head>`:**

```
<base href="/" />
```

**Create .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

**Add to `app.config`:**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

**Exemple to my `app.config`:**

```
function createState(name) {
    return {
        url: '/' + name + '/:id',
        templateUrl : 'templates/pages/' + name +'.html',
        controller : 'singlePage',
        resolve: {
           pageData: function(getData, $stateParams) {
                var params = $stateParams;
                params.type = this.self.name;
                return getData.getPageData(params.type, params)
           }
        }
    }
}
.state('info', createState('info'))
.state('news', createState('news'))
.state('event', createState('event'))

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: Well, google crawl bot is able to execute JavaScript (this feature was implemented not long ago). But the bot is still crawling URL like all time before. It is checking the `href` attribute  of all your `a`-Tags in your HTML markup and follow them up. If you are using the JavaScript state change functionality provided by `ui.router` the bot will never be able to follow this links. It also does not recognize the HTML5 URL route change. -> so no pages will be crawled / indexed.

Comment: I could create an answer which provides the stuff i said above. I can also give you a solution how to make the other URLs visible to the crawler bot.

Comment: @lin I really thank you for a full answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does the google crawler not follow my links / state changes created by UI Router?**

Well, google crawl bot is able to execute JavaScript (this feature was implemented not long ago).
But the bot is still crawling URL like all time before. It is checking the `href` attribute of
all your `a`-Tags in your HTML markup and follow them up. If you are using the JavaScript state
change functionality provided by `ui.router` the bot will never be able to follow this links.
It also does not recognize the HTML5 URL route changed. -> so no pages will be crawled / indexed

You can counteract that with some basic SEO functionalities. But there a still some limitations you
need to deal with. Some of this limitations are:

- Social content provided by meta tags. (Sharing a page on facebook while using `og:image`, etc. will not work with AngularJS E2E binding)
- The `title` tag used with E2E binding will not recognize by social media sharings.

**How to make the crawl bot indexing your pages?**
This is pretty easy, just create a `sitemap.xml` including all your URLs, upload it to your webserver and register it by using google webmastertools. The google bot will now crawl all the URLs you provided in your `sitemap.xml`and finally it will index your pages/URLs! =)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
 <url>
  <loc>http://example.com/</loc>
 </url>
 <url>
  <loc>http://example.com/anotherside/</loc>
 </url>
 <url>
  <loc>http://example.com/search/param1/param2</loc>
 </url>
</urlset>
```

We did this and it's working very well. You can create your `sitemap.xml` manually. We moved a step farther and automated this stuff. Our XML and `ui.routes`
are created on the backend side of our webapplications. So we have a configuration JSON file where we configure all our routes in. A script creates the XML and JavaScript `ui.routes`
automatically.

This is the result of what we did: https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:linslin.org&start=0

If you want to build a nice SEO/Social optimized page, don't use SPA applications like AngularJS. I would also not prefer to create a precompiler. It makes no sense to create a SPA application and precompile it. Before creating a precompiler you should go back to the roots by using PHP, Node.JS, Java, etc. to create a webapplication.

Comment: Thank you very much! you have a simple way to auto generate sitemaps (that deal with angular route)?

Comment: We created a custom script. But sorry. We will not share this.

Comment: Mhm, I dont know. You have to make it on your own.

Comment: You can use http://botmap.io/ to generate site map, it support JavaScript websites

Answer (score 2):

Google bots don't compile JavaScript, ui-router will not work here so when google bots come to crawl URL(no matter what url is), it will always get index page of the website. On server side detect bot by checking user agent and then You can use **phantomjs** to load angular app and compile html for bot.(that is what i have used for my application. on server i have node js)

read more from [here](https://www.deepcrawl.com/blog/best-practice/angular-js-and-seo/)

Comment: Precompiling isn't a good solution at all. There are a lot of limitations and problems with that. I would preffer to create a backend based application (PHP, Node, Java, etc.) before mixing a SPA Application with a precompiler.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment and answer. I have to learn a lot.

Comment: Precompiling only for the google bot is fine and even recommended as a workaround by google.