# Mean App, not crawling using google crawler

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, google-crawlers

I have developed a website using mean stack. In that hashbangs are present.
The website is not crawling the webpages.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS SEO - Once and for all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957366/angularjs-seo-once-and-for-all)

Comment: This will help ya.

Comment: @lin : Should I need to remove the hashbangs? Or i can create the sitemap.xml with hashbangs.